# Html and Javascript send email with text element

Tags: javascript, html, sharepoint

I have a form on sharepoint, that whenever a person fills that form, it will create a new page with the text added on the form.
I wanted to send an email using JavaScript and HTML with the copy of the various texts.
I have the id of the text and when i create the javascript code, it does not work.

HTML

```
<a onclick="javascript:sendEmailJobs()" class="mailto"></a>
```

JavaScript

```
function sendEmailJobs(){
    var JobCodePost = document.getElementById("RichHtmlFieldJobPostCodeJob").body;
    window.location.href = "mailto:?subject=Job Offer &body=" + body;
}
```

The id of said text is this:

```
<SharepointWebControls:NoteField ID="RichHtmlFieldJobPostCodeJob" FieldName="JobPostCode" runat="server"/>
```

Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you tried `document.getElementById("RichHtmlFieldJobPostCodeJob").innerHTML`? Also is the final rendered control ID `RichHtmlFieldJobPostCodeJob`?

Comment: I did, but i still nothing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Document elements don't have a "body" attribute, they have innerHTML and innerText. So your function should look like this:

```
function sendEmailJobs(){
    var JobCodePost = document.getElementById("RichHtmlFieldJobPostCodeJob").innerText;
    window.location.href = "mailto:?subject=Job Offer &body=" + JobCodePost;
}
```

Second thing is to verify that you are indeed selecting the correct element. Third thing is to point out that you can't use innerHTML because even if you get everything else right, mailto: links don't support formatted text.